Subype problem when making a struct callable
I'm trying to make a Matrix callable, in order to be able to use it, for instance, as a matrix of transformation functions.  I was able to come up with the following, which works OK.
rotation = [cos (x->-sin(x)) ; sin cos]

function (z::Matrix{Function})(x)
map(f->f(x), z)
end

rotate_pi_6 =  rotation(π/6)
rotate_pi_6 * [1,1]
#2-element Vector{Float64}:
# 0.36602540378443876
# 1.3660254037844386

So far, so good.
However, I discovered that if all the functions are the same, then the code no longer works.
[cos cos;cos cos](1)

   > ERROR: MethodError: objects of type Matrix{typeof(cos)} are not callable
   > Use square brackets [] for indexing an Array.
   > Stacktrace:
   >  [1] top-level scope
   >    @ REPL[109]:1

It seems that since we now have a Matrix{typeof(cos)} rather than a Matrix{Function}, no suitable dispatch is found.  Yet I would have expected this to work, since I imagine that 'cos' is a subtype of 'Function'.
I discovered this while trying
trm = [0 1 ; 2 3]
fn_pwr = n->x->x^n
trfm = map(fn_pwr, trm)
trfm(2)

> ERROR: MethodError: objects of type Matrix{var"#18#20"{Int64}} are not callable, etc...

Where I'd expect something like [1 2 ; 4 8]
Any suggestions, corrections, ideas, pointers most welcome.

trfm is a matrix of functions. Matrices are not calleble. So the resulting error is acceptable. [f(2) for f in trfm] might be the form you are looking for. Another way: invoke.(trfm, Tuple{Int}, (2,))

Thanks @Dan Getz, I do like that 'invoke' way of doing it, that's useful.  However, I'd have thought that the code I gave above would have made the matrix callable, after all it worked fine for the rotation matrix.  The point is that it stops working the minute something other than 'Function' is recognised to be the type, even if if it is a subtype of 'Function'.

While this is indeed possible would cation agaist it: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/style-guide/#Avoid-type-piracy

@DNF, re:  type piracy.   Thanks, I see the reason for the caveat, but assuming I need to use use this form, for whatever reason, would a solution be to create my own subtype, say 'CallableMatrix' for this use?

Your method should be defined as:
function (z::Matrix{<:Function})(x)
   map(f->f(x), z)
end

Than you can do:
julia> [cos cos](0)
1×2 Matrix{Float64}:
 1.0  1.0

There is however performance issue discussed at the end of this answer.
Explanation
When you create:
julia> [cos cos]
1×2 Matrix{typeof(cos)}:
 cos  cos

You can see that the type of the Matrix element is typeof(cos).
This is a matrix of concrete type, on the other hand Matrix{Function} is an abstract container:
julia> isconcretetype(typeof(cos)), isconcretetype(Function)
(true, false)

typeof(cos) is a subtype of Function, but is not equaul to the Function type:
julia> Matrix{typeof(cos)} <: Matrix{Function}, Matrix{typeof(cos)} <: Matrix{Function}
(false, false)

How to make your code 100x faster.
Constructors such [cos sin] create abstract containers and this is never good for the code performance. Instead you should take advantage of small unions that lead to huge performance gains.
Consider the following two definitions of your matrices of functions:
minsin(x) = -sin(x)
m1 = [cos minsin ; sin cos]
m2 = Matrix{Union{typeof(sin), typeof(minsin), typeof(cos)}}([cos minsin ; sin cos])

Let see how quickly the call is performed for each case:
julia> @btime $m1(0.0)
  2.400 μs (20 allocations: 688 bytes)
2×2 Matrix{Float64}:
 1.0  -0.0
 0.0   1.0

julia> @btime $m2(0.0)
  21.787 ns (1 allocation: 96 bytes)
2×2 Matrix{Float64}:
 1.0  -0.0
 0.0   1.0

Using small union makes m2 operations > 100x faster!!!

Perfect!  Thank you.  (I should have guessed but I'm still a bit new at this...)

Your code is not optimal. I will now update the answer to explain what you should do
